# T3 - Importing router from `../trpc`

Tags: trpc, t3

I am using t3-oss https://github.com/t3-oss.
In latest version of t3, when I want to create a new router and want to import {router} from trpc, I have error:

```
import { router, publicProcedure, protectedProcedure } from "../trpc";
```

Module '"../trpc"' has no exported member 'router'.ts(2305)

I checked the trpc documentation, and {router} should include the `trpc.ts' file. -> https://trpc.io/docs/router

What should I do? When is router in T3?

This is my trpc.ts
https://pastebin.com/g3Y0iP14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template generated by Create T3 App, all of the tRPC related stuff is exported from `./src/server/api/trpc.ts`. You can look in `./src/server/api/routers/example.ts` for an example of all the imports you'll need.

The specific thing you're looking for is called `createTRPCRouter`.